# How to solve Limit Exception : Too many query rows 50001

Tags: apex, rest, governorlimits, limitexception

I have a code which retrieves and displays  the results in the VF page from REST Web-Service.

In one sandbox , it's working fine. But in other sandbox it returns following error:

> Limit Exception Too many query rows: 50001 An unexpected error has
>   occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (Database).

Could any one of you tell me the cause of this error?

Comment: in your sandbox you have more than 50k records,so this error have occured,it's an governor limit.

Comment: Update your question and Post your code to get better solution.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your code to be more specific about your requirements and implementation. As it stands, it is difficult or impossible to recommend how to solve your problem because your question lacks sufficient detail.